# get Idictionnary from Ilist

Tags: c#

How to get a IDictionnay form a IList

Comment: That depends on how you want to map the elements from the list to the dictionary. Please add more context.

Comment: You should be a bit more specific what exactly you need to accomplish if you want to get an useful answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Linq to easily get a Dictionary from a List by using the ToDictionary extension method and supplying an expression to get the key - e.g.

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IList<Person> list = new List<Person> {new Person("Bob", 40), new Person("Jill", 35)};
        IDictionary<string, Person> dictionary = list.ToDictionary(x => x.Name);
    }
}

public class Person
{
    private readonly int _age;
    private readonly string _name;

    public Person(string name, int age)
    {
        _name = name;
        _age = age;
    }

    public int Age
    {
        get { return _age; }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, as Jon pointed out, if you need to use a different value for the Dictionary entries, you can also specify a second expression to get the value - as follows:

```
IDictionary<string, int> dictionary2 = list.ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => x.Age);
```

Comment: It may be worth noting that you can provide another projection to specify which value to use.

Answer (score 4):

A List has one component to it, and a Dictionary has two components. You can't simply convert them.

If you want your Dictionary to be `<int, object>`, where `int` is the index of the information in your List...

```
Dictionary<int, object> dict = new Dictionary<int, object>();
myList.ForEach(i => dict.Add(myList.IndexOf(i), i)); // Linq magic!
```

Replace `object` with your List type, and make sure you are `using System.Linq;`.

---

Or use [`ToDictionary()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary.aspx).